# How to get content in a flash embeded on a web site?

Tags: javascript, flash, web-applications

When dealing with simple web page, even if the page doesn't allow selecting text or right click, a browser with tools like inspect element is enough to get the content wanted.
But is it possible to get the content in an embeded flash? For example, in a flash online game there is a text paragraph, how can I select and copy these text? Will Javascript be useful or is it simply not possible?

Thanks!

Edit: 
For example, I'm playing an online card game, and I'm chatting with my opponent. And I'd like to save our chat somewhere. But I can't even select the text so it's impossible to copy and save it.. Hope it clears a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the text is embedded in the SWF, you may be able to select it as you would normal text.  If it's embedded as an image, you'll need to use OCR tools.

You can also try to decompile the SWF, using a program such as [Sothink's SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/)

Comment: Your method require downloading the flash game right? But my problem is that the information I want is sent immediately from the cloud, not static in the flash.

Comment: Can you provide an example?